# Ignoring null fields when mapping from one object to another (Transfer Object) in java?

Tags: java, if-statement, nullpointerexception

I'm writing a transfer object which simply maps an object coming back from a webservice to my own object: Car A to Car B.

a Car class has a mileage property.

```
CarB.setMileage(CarA.getMileage()); //if the CarA.getMileage() is null, then my setter fails and I get a nullPointerException
```

I have 50 fields, and am I correct that I just need write 50 separate checks for null before setting my fields?

i.e.,

```
if (CarA.getMileage() != null) {
   CarB.setMileage(CarA.getMileage());
}
```

Is there a way to avoid writing 50 separate if `!=null` check statements?

Comment: Show us your setter code. It must be more than `this.mileage = newVal;`

Comment: Are you sure that `CarA.getMileage()` is `null` and not just `CarA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little common but the better way is a common `method` in your bean `Class`

```
function String checkForNull(String str){

  //check for null and return corresponding
}
```

and then

`CarB.setMileage(checkForNull(CarA.getMileage()));`

Answer (score 2):

Try using Dozer mapping. It is a good tool and it can help ignoring null values too. It can be used to map two object programatically and using XML. You do not to specify any mapping between two fields of objects if attribute names in them are same. Following is the link:

http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/faq.html

Comment: Thanks fge. I think OP is just one of the case and may be there are more cases that can help our friend. So suggested it.

Comment: For your deleted answer: Please refer to [What is an acceptable answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/118694/182862). In its current form, your answer doesn't apply for points 8 to 12, so I posted a comment and downvoted it for not addressing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a static factory method in `CarB`:

```
// carA is of type CarA returned by the web service
CarB carB = CarB.fromCarA(carA);
```

All null checks etc would then be done in that factory method. Sample code:

```
public class CarB
{
    //....

    public static CarB fromCarA(final CarA carA)
    {
        if (carA == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("Where is my car???");

        final CarB ret = new CarB();

        // Supposing CarA returns an Integer...
        final Integer mileage = carA.getMileage();
        if (mileage != null)
            ret.setMileage(mileage);

        // etc etc, then
        return ret;
    }

    // etc
}
```

Comment: Or, similarly, `carB.setMileageFromCar(carA)` if you don't want a constructor.

Comment: @chessbot yup, but this requires one such method per attribute you want to set...

Comment: Fair enough; it looked like his code wanted to set attributes rather than construct a new car; perhaps something like `carB.setFrom(carA)`. Anyhow, it doesn't make particularly much difference.